# Angular orderBy string (range of numbers) as Number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects like so:

```
$scope.businesses = [ 
  { name: 'BusinessName', cost: '12' },
  { name: 'AnotherBusinessName', cost: '79-122' },
  { name: 'LastBusinessName', cost: '120' }
];
```

I'm trying to use an `orderBy` to sort by cost, like so:

```
<ul>
    ...
    <li ng-click="sortProps('-cost')">Price: High to Low</li>
</ul>
```

with `sortProps` being declared like this:

```
$scope.sortProps = function(prop) {
    $scope.sortBy = prop;
    $scope.reverse = false;
};
```

For some reason, when ordering by `'-cost'` (or its opposite), I always get
12 > 120 > 79-122 to display. When sorting by `'-cost'` I would expect to see 120 > 79-122 > 12. I know where the problem is stemming from (cost being a string in the object), but I'm not entirely sure how to cast this as a `Number` while still displaying the full price range, such as 79-122.

I've tried `parseFloat(business.cost)` when constructing my `$scope.businesses`, but this strips out anything after the `-`, which is to be expected. But strangely enough, this was still giving me the sort order of 12 > 120 > 79 (parsed from 79-122).

I've also tried something similar to:

```
$scope.sortProps = function(prop) { 
  if (prop === 'cost' || prop === '-cost') {
    angular.forEach($scope.businesses, function(business) { 
      business.cost = parseFloat(business.cost);
    });
  }
  // ...
};
```

in an effort to only cast as a Number when sorting by cost. I'm lost, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution has two parts:

1. "markup" the data with a "costNum" property (which is a number)'
2. Use orderBy filter normally on that new property.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MHks2D8cYYetluJocaKV?p=preview)

JavaScript

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
   angular.module('app', []).controller('TestCtrl', Controller);
   function Controller($scope){
     $scope.orderByProp = null;
     $scope.sort = function() {
       $scope.orderByProp = 'costNum';
     };
     $scope.reverseSort = function() {
       $scope.orderByProp = $scope.orderByProp === 'costNum' ? '-costNum' : 'costNum';
     };
     $scope.removeSort = function() {
       $scope.orderByProp = null;
     };
     $scope.businesses = [ 
      {name: 'Business Zero', cost: '345'},
      {name: 'Business One', cost: '12'},
      {name: 'Another Two', cost: '79-122'},
      {name: 'Business Three', cost: '120'}, 
      {name: 'Business Four', cost: '20'}, 
      {name: 'Business Five', cost: '80'}
    ];
    function markupBiz() {
      for(var i = 0, len = $scope.businesses.length; i < len; i++) {
        $scope.businesses[i].costNum = parseFloat($scope.businesses[i].cost);
      }
    }
    markupBiz();
  }
})();
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <button ng-click="sort()">Sort</button>
  <button ng-click="reverseSort()">Reverse sort</button>
  <button ng-click="removeSort()">Remove sort</button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="business in businesses | orderBy:orderByProp">
      {{business.name}}: ${{business.cost}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, this ended up being my solution too. Going to mark as answer for anyone else who might run into this in the future. Thanks!